# "Justify Content" on my flex unordered list is not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple Flexbox footer. When the screen gets below 580px, the layout changes as you can see below.

I have two primary issues:

1. The justify-content property on the `<ul>` doesn't seem to kick in. If I've made the `<ul>` a `display: flex` item, surely the child elements should be flex items, no?  On the mobile version of the footer, the `<li>` items stay stuck to the right-hand side.
2. Why is the right-hand side container (that switches to being the bottom item on the mobile view) so much bigger in height than its sibling at the mobile size?  There is no extra padding or height value added to this item.

** Note - I've put a 1px border around every element to make it easier to see what is going on.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.footer-inner {
  background: blue;
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
}

#footerright {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#footerright ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#footerright ul li {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .footer-inner {
    justify-content: center;
    min-width: 240px;
  }
  #footerright {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #footerright ul {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-inner" id="footerleft">&copy<span id="footer-year">Year</span>&nbspThe Company</div>
  <div class="footer-inner" id="footerright">
    <ul>
      <li id="facebook">Twi</li>
      <li id="instagram">Fac</li>
      <li id="twitter">Ins</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

[View on CodePen](https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/RjQqPe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the righthand side container so much bigger in height than its
>   sibling at the mobile size?.

Because when in non-mobile size, the default value of flex *row* items's `align-items` kicks in, which is `stretch`, and make items on the same row equally high, which is not the case when wrapped, or using flex *column* direction, where they instead collapse to their own height, based on margin, border, padding and content.

*In this case, if you remove the preset padding/margin from the `ul`, it will collapse to the `li`'s size, where they appear to have an equal height, though based on e.g. different font size, etc., they might become unequal again.*

---

> Flexbox “Justify Content” not working

The *margin/padding* reset (`ul {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`) will also take care of the small left offset the `ul` suffer from, in both mobile and non-mobile view, though in mobile view it is more obvious, which I also guess is what you meant with *`justify-content` doesn't seem to kick in*.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the "right-alignment" in mobile view: Add `padding-left: 0;` to the `ul` to avoid the default padding of `ul`s which causes a horizontal offset from the centered position.

And concerning the size of the second container: Add `padding: 0` to `.footer-inner` and `margin: 0` to `#footerright ul` to reset the default paddings and margins:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOQwBV

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by adding the basic CSS browser reset (equal height problem) and replacing the `justify-content: center` property inside the `#footerright > ul` to `align-items: center`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.footer-inner {
  background: blue;
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
}

#footerright {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#footerright ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#footerright ul li {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .footer-inner {
    justify-content: center;
    min-width: 240px;
  }
  #footerright {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #footerright > ul {
    /*justify-content: center;*/
    align-items: center; /* because of the changed direction this is now horizontal alignment / centering */
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-inner" id="footerleft">&copy<span id="footer-year">Year</span>&nbspThe Company</div>
  <div class="footer-inner" id="footerright">
    <ul>
      <li id="facebook">Twi</li>
      <li id="instagram">Fac</li>
      <li id="twitter">Ins</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Certain browsers have default "User Agent Stylesheets", that are the default styles applied to elements on the page. In Webkit, the browser adds a few properties to your `ul` that are affecting your styles:

```
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
```

As you can see, there are margins being added before and after your `ul`, causing the mobile issue you described, where the `ul` is taller than its sibling. There is also padding, which is shifting your contents to the right.

To reset these styles, you just need to set those defaults to zero like so:

```
#footerright ul {
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

**Note:** you don't *need* to reset the -webkit- rules above, you'd also be fine just resetting the `padding-left`, `margin-top`, and `margin-bottom`.